# PHP script wont die on control +c

Tags: php, linux, wget

I have a PHP script that uses exec to launch some commands in Linux. It's a simple wget that is set to die after five minutes hour. The issue I am facing is if I do Control + c as the script is running it wont die till I kill the actual PID of the wget. I tried using pcntl_signal as well as using exec/system/shell_exec etc. and none of them worked. The code I am using is:

```
<?PHP
system('/usr/bin/timeout 300 wget -c --tries=0 --read-timeout=200 -O /tmp/ll.mp3  http://15323.live.streamtheworld.com:80/WABCAM_SC');  
?>
```

Comment: I suppose it is because you kill `/usr/bin/timeout`, not `wget`. You forgot to share your `pcntl_signal` code :-?

Comment: That seems plausible (that I am just killing timeout). I wanted to use set_time_limit in php but that would kill my entire script. I just want the wget to end after X time. Also you can see my pcntl code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I do Control + c as the script is running it wont die

This is because the signal `SIGINT` generated from the terminal by typing the interrupt key is sent only to the foreground process group for the terminal, and [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) segregates itself and the given command from the foreground process group by executing `setpgid(0, 0)`.
Now, since the `SIGINT` is not sent to the `timeout` command, a foreground process would have to handle the signal and thereupon kill the `timeout` command. As we learn from the failure of an other answer, PHP is not well suited for such signal handling, but we can use a little wrapper script (let's call it `timeout.sh`) for this:

```
time=$1; shift
timeout $time "$@"&
trap "kill $!" INT
wait $!
```

---

```
<?PHP
system('timeout.sh 300 wget -c --tries=0 --read-timeout=200 -O /tmp/ll.mp3 …');  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to declare the [`ticks` directive](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php#control-structures.declare.ticks) to make it work in PHP 4.3.0 and newer (see the [manual page for `pcntl_signal`](https://www.php.net/pcntl_signal)).

Then you have to register the signal and the callback function which is called when the signal is received. In your case, you want the signal `SIGINT` which is generated when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> pressed.

```
declare(ticks = 1);

// callback function called when signal is received
function shutdown($signal)
{
    echo 'Interrupted using CTRL + C';

    // you probably don't need this condition, just exit should be enough
    if (($signal === SIGINT)) {
        exit;
    }
}

// register the callback function for the specific signal
// SIGINT in this case is generated when you press CTRL + C
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'shutdown');
```

Comment: [root@m-n ~]# php /tmp/l.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Process_Sync' not found in /tmp/l.php on line 11
[root@m-n ~]#

Comment: Edited. Try now, please.

Comment: Below didn't work either.

<?PHP
declare(ticks = 1);
  
function shutdown($signal)
{
    echo 'Interrupted using CTRL + C';

    // you probably don't need this condition, just exit should be enough
    if (($signal === SIGINT)) {
        exit;
    }
}

// register the callback function for the specific signal
// SIGINT in this case is generated when you press CTRL + C
pcntl_signal(SIGINT, 'shutdown');

system('/usr/bin/timeout 3610 wget --tries=0 --read-timeout=200 -O /l.mp3  http://myurl.com:80/_SC');
?>